# How can I recursively access named elements of sub lists?

Tags: r

I have a nested list, I would like to get the "x" element of each sub list. What is the easiest way to do that ?

```
my.list <- list(a = list(x = 1, y = 1), 
                b = list(x = 2, y = 2), 
                c = list(x = 3, y = 3))
```

I'm actualy doing it using an anonymous function in `lapply` :

```
lapply(my.list, function(x) x$x)
```

But why this doesn't work ? And what should I change to make it work ?

```
lapply(my.list, `$`, name = `x`)
```

Thank you.

Comment: You have a nested list

Comment: `lapply(my.list, "[[", "x")` would also work

Comment: Thanks docendo discimus ! That's what I was looking for I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try

```
sapply(my.list, `[[`, "x")
# a b c 
#1 2 3
```